# Custom Accordion Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to Customize accordion through jQuery, but it's not working.
can anybody help me out?

My sample code is as below, let me know if there will be any problem.

Thanks in advance

```js
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".accordion li h5").click(function () {  
      var current_li = $(this).parent();
      $(".accordion li div").each(function(i,el) {   
       if($(el).parent().is(current_li)) {    
        $(el).prev().toggleClass("plus");
        $(el).slideToggle();    
       } else{
        $(el).prev().removeClass("plus");
        $(el).slideUp();
       }
      });
        });
     $('.accordion li > div').hide();
      $('.accordion li h5').first().addClass("plus");
      $('.accordion li > div').first().show().addClass("plus");
     });
    </script>
```

```css
    .accordion ul{
     border-bottom:#ecebe9 solid 1px;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    .accordion ul li{
     border-left:#ecebe9 solid 1px;
     border-right:#ecebe9 solid 1px;
        list-style:none;
    }
    .accordion ul li h5{
     font-size:12px;
     color:#333333;
     font-weight:bold;
     background:#f7f6f5;
     border-top:#ecebe9 solid 1px;
     border-left:#ecebe9 solid 1px;
     border-right:#ecebe9 solid 1px;
     padding:12px 15px 12px 40px;
     line-height:19px;
     cursor:pointer;
     position:relative;
    }
    .accordion ul li h5.plus{
     border-bottom:#ecebe9 solid 1px;
    }
    .accordion ul li > div{
     font-size:12px;
     color:#333333;
     line-height:20px;
     padding:15px 15px 15px 40px;
    }
    .accordion ul li > div a{
     color:#7f0a19;
    }
    .accordion ul li h5:before{
     content:"";
     background:#f00;
     width:11px;
     height:11px;
     opacity:0.7;
     position:absolute;
     left:14px;
     top:14px;
     transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out  0s;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out  0s;
     -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out  0s;
    }
    .accordion ul li h5.plus:before{
     opacity:1;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="faq">
        <div class="accordion">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <h5>Title Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</h5>
                    <div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the</div>
                </li>
                 <li>
                    <h5>Title Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</h5>
                    <div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the</div>
                </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I have a question here...Why are you not hiding the <div> through CSS then make it visible through JQuery onClick

Answer (score 1):

Your code does work. [Here is the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9ypb8fem/) and below is the code snippet like you posted.

There is simply error in the way you added the jquery library to the snippet. You should either add an external source (link to jquery), or use the `<script>` tag, not both.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".accordion li h5").click(function () {
        var current_li = $(this).parent();
        $(".accordion li div").each(function (i, el) {
            if ($(el).parent().is(current_li)) {
                $(el).prev().toggleClass("plus");
                $(el).slideToggle("fast");
            } else {
                $(el).prev().removeClass("plus");
                $(el).slideUp("fast");
            }
        });
    });
    $('.accordion li > div').hide();
    $('.accordion li h5').first().addClass("plus");
    $('.accordion li > div').first().show().addClass("plus");
});
```

```css
.accordion ul {
    border-bottom:#ecebe9 solid 1px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.accordion ul li {
    border-left:#ecebe9 solid 1px;
    border-right:#ecebe9 solid 1px;
    list-style:none;
}
.accordion ul li h5 {
    font-size:12px;
    color:#333333;
    font-weight:bold;
    background:#f7f6f5;
    border-top:#ecebe9 solid 1px;
    border-left:#ecebe9 solid 1px;
    border-right:#ecebe9 solid 1px;
    padding:12px 15px 12px 40px;
    line-height:19px;
    cursor:pointer;
    position:relative;
}
.accordion ul li h5.plus {
    border-bottom:#ecebe9 solid 1px;
}
.accordion ul li > div {
    font-size:12px;
    color:#333333;
    line-height:20px;
    padding:15px 15px 15px 40px;
}
.accordion ul li > div a {
    color:#7f0a19;
}
.accordion ul li h5:before {
    content:"";
    background:#f00;
    width:11px;
    height:11px;
    opacity:0.7;
    position:absolute;
    left:14px;
    top:14px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.accordion ul li h5.plus:before {
    opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faq">
    <div class="accordion">
        <ul>
            <li>
                 <h5>Title Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</h5>

                <div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the</div>
            </li>
            <li>
                 <h5>Title Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</h5>

                <div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    <div class="faq">
      <div class="accordion">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <h5 class="header">Title Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</h5>
            <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the</div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <h5 class="header">Title Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</h5>
            <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the</div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

jQuery:

```
   function MyAccordion() {
     $('.accordion .content').hide();
     $('.accordion .header').click(function() {
     if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
          $(this).nextUntil('.header').slideUp(250);
          $(this).removeClass('active');
      } else {
          $(this).nextUntil('.header').slideDown(250);
          $(this).siblings('.header').nextUntil('.header').slideUp(250);
          $(this).addClass('active');
          $('.accordion .header').not(this).removeClass('active');
       }
     });
   }
   MyAccordion();
```

Add a minus sign for the **"active"** class. The script adds class active to the `<h5>` tag above the open accordion segment.

JsFiddle [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/p6ep2tsp/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you want the click of a 'header' to not only open content below it, but close the other contents, use:

```js
function MyAccordion() {
  $('.accordion .content').hide();
  $('.accordion .header').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
      $(this).nextUntil('.header').slideUp(250);
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    } else {
      $('.accordion .header').removeClass('active');
      $('.accordion .content').slideUp(250);
      $(this).nextUntil('.header').slideDown(250);
      $(this).siblings('.header').nextUntil('.header').slideUp(250);
      $(this).addClass('active');
      $('.accordion .header').not(this).removeClass('active');
    }
  });
}
MyAccordion();
```

```css
.accordion ul {
    border-bottom:#ecebe9 solid 1px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.accordion ul li {
    border-left:#ecebe9 solid 1px;
    border-right:#ecebe9 solid 1px;
    list-style:none;
}
.accordion ul li h5 {
    font-size:12px;
    color:#333333;
    font-weight:bold;
    background:#f7f6f5;
    border-top:#ecebe9 solid 1px;
    border-left:#ecebe9 solid 1px;
    border-right:#ecebe9 solid 1px;
    padding:12px 15px 12px 40px;
    line-height:19px;
    cursor:pointer;
    position:relative;
}
.accordion ul li h5.active {
    border-bottom:#ecebe9 solid 1px;
}
.accordion ul li > div {
    font-size:12px;
    color:#333333;
    line-height:20px;
    padding:15px 15px 15px 40px;
}
.accordion ul li > div a {
    color:#7f0a19;
}
.accordion ul li h5:before {
    content:"";
    background:#f00;
    width:11px;
    height:11px;
    opacity:0.7;
    position:absolute;
    left:14px;
    top:14px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.accordion ul li h5.active:before {
    opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faq">
  <div class="accordion">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <h5 class="header">Title Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</h5>
        <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the</div>
      </li>
      <li>
         <h5 class="header">Title Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</h5>
         <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the</div>
      </li>
      <li>
         <h5 class="header">Title Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</h5>
         <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the</div>
      </li>
      <li>
         <h5 class="header">Title Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</h5>
         <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```